# ValueError: View function did not return a response in Python using Flask

Tags: python, flask

Edit: This is not a duplicate question.  I am not asking what is wrong with the code.  I very clearly said I know it's throwing an error because a view must `return` something.  I'm asking why would the tutorial provide code that is going to throw an error and then neither prepare the user for that error or use that error to teach a lesson.  The answer is, the tutorial is not perfect.

Original post: I'm following the Flask quickstart tutorial at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/.  I'm roughly 2/5 down the page when it has me do URL building.  The below code is directly from the tutorial, but it throws the titular ValueError when I try to visit localhost:5000/.  I know that a view must `return` something and that's why it's throwing the error.

**My primary question is, am I missing something in the tutorial?**  A tutorial shouldn't result in an error unless it's trying to teach you something by that error, but there's no mention of expecting an error.  Rather, it seems to indicate it should work with the below code.  I don't want to push ahead on the tutorial if I've missed something basic.

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index(): pass

@app.route('/login')
def login(): pass

@app.route('/user/<username>')
def profile(username): pass

with app.test_request_context():
    print url_for('index')
    print url_for('login')
    print url_for('login', next='/')
    print url_for('profile', username='John Doe')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see it is on python shell and docs says:

> **test_request_context()**: It tells Flask to behave as though it is handling a request, even though we are interacting with it through a Python shell.

Tutorial does not say write this code to a file. If you do something like this:

```
#test.py
from flask import Flask, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index(): pass
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
$ python test.py
/
/login
/login?next=%2F
/user/John%20Doe
```

So when you hit localhost:5000 on browser you will get error View function did not return a response.

**My primary question is, am I missing something in the tutorial?** Yes probably you are missing to see it is on python shell.

Answer (score 1):

The view function in Flask should always return Response object, otherwise the `View function did not return a response` error occures. It seems that the code in the example is given just for refenence and is not supposed to work out of the box.

See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#about-responses for more details about responses.

Answer (score 1):

You will get an error accessing `localhost:5000` because you are not running the `app`. And you are right, it should also return something.

The goal of this block:

```
with app.test_request_context():
    print url_for('index')
    print url_for('login')
    print url_for('login', next='/')
    print url_for('profile', username='John Doe')
```

is only to show what urls generated by `url_for` would look like.

So you can run your file with `python your_file.py` and see the output in the shell.